# Nesting IF while doing AD Actions

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to create a script that reads a list of emails from a CSV, then remove them from an AD Group along with posting if user was removed, didn't belong to the group, or not found.
This code works but the results display are wrong, it shows as if nothing was done while the real action was already done (checked in AD)
Can someone check my code and help with what's wrong in there (so sorry for the formatting, i'm newbie x_x)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ1B0.png)

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\*******\users.csv -Delimiter ";"

$groupname = "My Group"
$count = 0
$notmember = 0
$notfound = 0
cls
ForEach ($User in $ADUsers) {
$mail = $User.email

$search = get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($mail)'" -Properties samaccountname

    if ($search) {  
                $action = remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Members $search.samaccountname -Confirm:$false 
                         if ($action) {
                                Write-Host "done on $($mail)"
                                $count ++}
                         else {
                               Write-Host "$($mail) is not a member."
                                $notmember ++}
                  }

    else {
        "$($mail) not found."
           $notfound ++
         }
}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Total input users: $($users.count)"
Write-Host "Done: $($count)"
Write-Host "not done: $($notmember)"
Write-Host "not found: $($notfound)"
```

Comment: take a look at the docs for the `remove-ADGroupMember` cmdlet. **_it does not output anything unless you tell it to do so._**

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks for your guide ! do you have any idea on how to have an output? couldn't find big things in Microsoft forum

Comment: found it ! for reference, remove needed to have a parameter -PassThru

Comment: that is the parameter i was hinting at. glad to know you found it & got things working! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

found it ! for reference, remove needed to have a parameter -PassThru